# Prefix and suffix selection while retaining any formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Sub Quote_Text()
    With Selection.Range
        .Text = "<link>" & .Text & "</link>"
        .Select   '<<<<<
    End With
End Sub
```

This code tags the selected text correctly, but if any of the selected words are bold etc the formatting is lost. Is there a setting to retain format? Or another way of achieving the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Sub Quote_Text()
    With Selection.Range
        .InsertBefore "<link>"
        .InsertAfter "</link>"
    End With

    ' and if you want to update Selection
    With Selection
        ' .MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:= (-1) * Len("<link>")
        .MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len("</link>")
    End With        

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this was part of what I needed and now I have a solution that works and does not touch the formatting of the original text. I needed more than my original request. I hope it is ok to post that below as it could be helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. If there is more to follow, my understanding is that at StackExchange the preference is for single, focused questions. I believe it's frowned upon to add more to a question one you've accepted an answer. Unless you're just clarifying, consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Extending this requirement a little.
I needed to go from this to this.
 
This is what worked for me. Again I don't loose the format of the original text, and there is no space after the final  which is what I need.

lobortis ante. ***Mauris*** eu molestie magna
lobortis ante. <link>Mauris </link>***Mauris*** eu molestie magna.

```
Dim textOriginal As selection
Set textOriginal = selection

With selection.Range
    .InsertBefore "<link>" & textOriginal & "</link>"
End With
```